# Renew/Extend JWT in API before it expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

The project I'm working on requires sending JWT token to the client via an endpoint when they login.

The JWT token returned is cached in cookie and any subsequent client requests will be sent with the token in the header that's obtained from the cookie.

The token needs to be renewed X minutes before it expires.

When the token is renewed, it will be sent back to the cookie and the client would get the new token from the cookie.

I wonder how I can intercept the token before it reaches the endpoints that are authorized by this token. Or is there any other way to do it? If not, how can I add customization to the JWT authentication handler? Thanks!

Comment: It's client who should be tracking the token expiry and renew when needed. Authorization or authentication server should not worry about the token expiry. It should check the token if token is valid or not and if not valid then it should just return appropriate error message. Client should check the expiry of token before making any API calls and if the token is about to expire it should renew the token before making API call.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It's the requirement of the project that I have no control over.....

Comment: Then you should write a custom attribute where you check the token expiry and if it's expired you renew the token first and then proceed with the API request. This is actually a security hole coz any one can call the API with expired token token and get the new token.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm using  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)], So are you saying on top of this I have to add a custom attribute? When the client calls the API, they send the JWT in the header and the API also compares this with the cookie by checking Request.Cookies["token"] against Request.Headers["token"]. Also this renewal does not happen if the token already expires.

Comment: API should not check client cookies. It should only check the header and check the token in the header. You should create a new attribute class inherited from Authorize attribute and override the necessary methods.

Comment: Could you please tell me that your jwt token issuer and the jwt auth is in the same project? Do you know the jwt token generated codes? If you know the token generated codes, then you could use `context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]` to get the token and use `new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(token).ValidTo` to get the expire the date, then you could check the expire the datetime and then recall the issue token method add update the cookie.

Comment: @BrandoZhang yes, the jwt token issuer and jwt auth are in the same project so there's no problem calling the token generating method to 'renew' it. My problem is where should this 'regenerating' happen. I'm using [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] so validating JWT is taken care of automatically. Should I customize the scheme to add this renewing part? Thanks!